# Google App Engine - Getting Sessions working with Python 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, session-variables

First of all, I'm brand new to GAE, so its possible I'm doing this the wrong way - but I've used PHP before and session was how I kept persistent data. I'm using Python 2.7 because that is what I use for all my other Python development - although I'm beginning to wonder if downgrading to 2.5 might be a valid solution, if not an ideal one.

The scenario is that I'm building a proof-of-concept site, and I need to have a 'dummy' login button that simply sets a session variable called **'user'** with a value of **'admin'**.  I then want to check in the navigation template to see if the variable is set, and if so I'll add some extra menu commands.  Very simple.  *(Note: I KNOW this isn't secure, sensible or anything that should be done - the problem is that session is not working, not what I'm doing with it - I'm doing a couple of other things in the code using session - none of them are working when deployed)*

It seems there are a few different session libraries for GAE with Python and I tried the one that was most widely recommended in Google searches - [gaeutilities](http://gaeutilities.appspot.com/), but this caused errors and wouldn't work (I eventually stumbled across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652820/error-on-windows-using-session-from-appengine-utilities) to explain that its just not compatible with Python 2.7).  A little more searching led me to [this](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~csev/books/gae/files/util.zip) library from appenginelearn.com which I dropped in and it worked perfectly... until I deployed it - then it just does nothing.  I'd love some pointers or advice as to why this might be failing.  Here is the relevant code that I'm using:

I put the util library directory from appenginelearn.com in the root of the application directory, then imported Session:

```
from util.sessions import Session
```

Then I added the Login and Logout classes:

```
class LogIn(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.session = Session()
        self.session['user'] = 'admin'
        # Return the user to the page they logged in from
        referer = self.request.environ['HTTP_REFERER'] \
                if 'HTTP_REFERER' in self.request.environ \
                else '/'
        self.redirect(referer)

class LogOut(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.session = Session()
        self.session.delete_item('user')
        self.redirect('/')
```

And the following (awful) code in the main class (this will be done for all pages in the demo)

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.session = Session()
        logging.info('Main page fired up')
        if 'user' in self.session:
            user = self.session['user']
        else:
            user = None

        template_values = {
            'user': user
            }
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('main.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

And then this in the HTML template file

```
  {% if user %}
      <p>Welcome, {{user}}</p>
  {% endif %}
```

And the errors in the log:

```
2012-10-04 02:51:28.084 /login 302 143ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4
*ip address removed* - - [04/Oct/2012:02:51:28 -0700] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 136 "*site-removed*" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4" "*site-removed*" ms=144 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000015 instance=*instance removed*
**I** 2012-10-04 02:51:28.080
Creating session session-*session number removed*
**E** 2012-10-04 02:51:28.084
Set-Cookie: appengine-simple-session-sid=*session number removed*; Path=/
```

Comment: Why not use the webapp2 sessions : http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html

Comment: Because I didn't know it existed... thanks for the link, I've now implemented it and its working perfectly :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you seen webapp2 sessions? It's all built in and you can get started right away.

https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html

> This module provides a lightweight but flexible session support for webapp2.
>   It has three built-in backends: secure cookies, memcache and datastore. New backends can be added extending CustomBackendSessionFactory.
>   The session store can provide multiple sessions using different keys, even using different backends in the same request, through the method SessionStore.get_session(). By default it returns a session using the default key from configuration.

```
import webapp2

from webapp2_extras import sessions

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def dispatch(self):
        # Get a session store for this request.
        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

        try:
            # Dispatch the request.
            webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
        finally:
            # Save all sessions.
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
        # Returns a session using the default cookie key.
        return self.session_store.get_session()

# To set a value:
self.session['foo'] = 'bar'

# To get a value:
foo = self.session.get('foo')
```

Then it's real easy to build a login system around this, seems you've already done it already. And you get to use the datastore and/or memcache with the webapp2 sessions, as preferred.

Comment: Perfect! - just what I needed... and the code in each page handler class is now simpler as well.  Thanks :)

Comment: And it really flies from memcache!