# Login concept against xml site

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, authentication

I need help to figure out how to make a login on my site on GAE through another site.
I need to validate against another site and will get a xml response like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <api version='1'>
    <loggedIn/>
  </api>
```

or

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <api version='1'>
  <error message="NotAuthorized"/>
</api>
```

How can I make a login,  I have't tried it before.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

I found this Post and started making something simple with sessions.

[Google App Engine - Getting Sessions working with Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737008/google-app-engine-getting-sessions-working-with-python-2-7)

http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html

I would like to use the Auth modele instead, but can't figure it out.
http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/auth.html#api-webapp2-extras-auth