# user / session variables appengine with python

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, session-variables

I'm new to app engine, python an web development in general. I have an issue that i don't know how to solve. I want to maintain in the server an tuple with values that the user select. I pass this values to the server in the parameters of the page.

But the problem is that this tuple is modified by all the users and I want that each user can have his own values. The users aren't identified.

I've been looking for how to solve it, and I found some answers here in stackoverflow, but major part of them are more than 2 years old, and I think that I need to use the library gaeutilities, but not sure about it, and If Google have an “official” solution to maintain session variables with python in app engine.

I defined the var “categoria” as a class variable,

```
class returnElements(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    categoria = []
    def get(self):
        …...
        cat = str(self.request.get("cat"))
        self.categoria.append(cat)
        …...

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/returnElements', returnElements), 
     …....
```

and here the url

```
http://localhost:13080/returnElements?cat=Sudaderas
```

It works fine, but just with one user at time :-(

By the way Im new to stackoverflow, sorry in advance if the question isn't accurate or solved in another thread.

Comment: An answers age does not indicate it has low value, quite the opposite. Have you *tried* any of those other answers? I've actually answered this exact same question here and the answer is still valid!

Comment: Thanks @PaulCollingwood I just found your answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737008/google-app-engine-getting-sessions-working-with-python-2-7) I'm going to try with webapp2_extras.

Comment: good luck! Any problems just ask :)

Comment: ups! A long time but I forgot to answer: Just to say tyhat the solution with webapp2_extras works fine for me :-) If someone is having the same issue just check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737008/google-app-engine-getting-sessions-working-with-python-2-7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any web app, you must *never* store user-specific data in module or class-level variables as they will be shared by all users.

If you need to persist data for a user, save it in the datastore! That's what it's for. There are various implementations of user-specific sessions, such as the gaeutilities library which you link to. That library has full documentation which you should read.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I will try webapp2_extras. But really thanks for the advice about class level variables.